# Не отправляет значения с тега <option> в базу данных

Tags: php, html, sql

HTML:

```
<select name="type_users" id="type_users">
    <option name="server1" value="server1">CRMP-RP</option>
    <option name="server3" value="server2">SMTHELSE</option>
    <option name="server3" value="server3">SMTHELSE2</option>
</select>
```

php:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("","","","") OR DIE('Ошибка подключения к базе данных');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['username']));
  $password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password1']));
  $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password2']));
  $type_users = $_POST['type_users'];
  if(!empty($username) && !empty($password1) && !empty($password2) && ($password1 == $password2)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `signup` WHERE username = '$username'";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
      $query ="INSERT INTO `signup` (username, password, server) VALUES ('$username', ('$password2', ('$type_users')))";
      mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
      echo 'well.';
      mysqli_close($dbc);
      exit();
    }
    else {
      echo 'Логин уже существует';
    }

  }
}
```

Но при этом значения логина и пароль отправляет в базу.

Comment: Удостоверьтесь, что элемент `select` находится внутри тэга `form`.

Answer (score 0):

Стоило бы наверное проверить что у вас приходит в сам `$_POST['type_users']` и отталкиваться от этих данных.

Хотя бы:

HTML:

```
<select name="type_users" id="type_users">
    <option value="server1">CRMP-RP</option>
    <option value="server2">SMTHELSE</option>
    <option value="server3">SMTHELSE2</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
$query ="INSERT INTO `signup` (username, password, server) VALUES ('$username', '$password2', '$type_users')";
```

Answer (score 0):

если хочешь отправить переменную из тэга

option, то Имя этой переменной должно задаваться в тэге select name='...', а в option value="..." - указывается само значение переменной! Тогда в базе окажется переменная с именем отсюда - select name='...',   но значение этой переменной будет считаться отсюда -  option value="..."